# How do I restore a menu to the Visual Studio 2008 menu bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My Alt key was unknowingly stuck down and I tried to open my Window Menu in VS, which resulted in removing the menu from the bar.

My question is, how the heck do I get it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on one of the visible Toolbars, select **Customize...**
(or **Tools > Customize...** menu)

Then in the **Toolbars** list, select **Menu Bar**, then click the **Reset** button